# Finishing moves for each enemy type to get extra Demon Fangs?

Tags: okami

In Okami, after an enemy is defeated they will fly through the air in slow motion. You can receive extra Demon Fangs if you finish the enemy off with the correct special move. (For Imps, you can just slice them in half, or for Bud Ogres, you can use Blossom)

Does every enemy have a special finisher move that grants extra Demon Fangs after killing them? Which enemies require which moves?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/943732-okami/faqs/45047):

- The following are floraled by Power Slash:

  - Green Imp
  - Red Imp
  - Yellow Imp
  - Black Imp
  - Bell Guardian
  - Chimera
  - Dead Fish
  - Thunder Doom Mirror
  - Tube Fox
  - Clay Flyer
  - Dogu
- The following are floraled by Bloom:

  - Bud Ogre
- The following are floraled by Cherry Bomb:

  - Headless Guardian
  - Halo Guardian
  - Executioner Guardian
  - Bucket Namahage
- The following are floraled by Galestorm (or other source of wind):

  - Blue Imp
  - Crow Tengu
  - Fire Eye
  - Thunder Ear
  - Poltergeist
  - Namahage
  - Blade Namahage
  - Cannon Namahage
  - Umbrella Namahage
- The following are floraled by Deluge (or other source of water):

  - Blue Cyclops
- The following are floraled by Veil of Mist:

  - Ubume
  - Earth Nose
  - Wind Doom Mirror
  - Clay Soldier
  - Clay Samurai
  - Clay Shogun
  - Clay Drummer
- The following are floraled by Inferno (or other source of fire):

  - Ice Mouth
  - Ice Doom Mirror
  - Igloo Turtle
  - Bull Charger
- The following are floraled by Thunderstorm (or other source of lightning):

  - Red/Blue Oni
  - Jiro/Saburo/Ichiro
- The following are floraled by Blizzard (or other source of ice):

  - Great Tengu